# WEBrick-like php server?

Tags: php, web-server, web-hosting

I'm a Rails developer with some Drupal 6 experience.

When I'm developing on Rails, I'm used to modifying my code and then relaunching:

```
cd /my/project/path
script/server
```

This will launch an instance of [WEBrick](http://microjet.ath.cx/webrickguide/html/), and my site will be available at http://localhost:3000, which is very convenient for testing - it doesn't require me to configure any Apache files and doesn't require admin rights.

In contrast now the only way I know for serving PHP pages is configuring an Apache virtualhost, which isn't as "agile".

Is there something as convenient as WEBrick, for PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it quite easy to use lighttpd in development, e.g.:

```
lighttpd -f lighttpd.conf
lighttpd -f ~/.lighttpd/drupal.conf
lighttpd -f ~/path-to-your-project/etc/lighttpd.conf
```

See also answers to similar question at stackoverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437664/using-webrick-to-serve-php-web-applications

Answer (score 3):

A [built-in webserver](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/builtinwebserver) will be included in a future version of PHP.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I could not find any other server, so I'm accepting this as valid for now.